# strlen function incompatible w/loop, loop variable incompatible

Tags: c++, loops, incompatibility

Ok I've been looking everywhere and I can't find the proper way to do this. I simply want to take in a string, put that string in the array and output the contents. However, I want to do it dependent on the size of the string which the user enters in. And I was getting weird errors such as incompatibility and I would like to know why please, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 4000;
    string y;

    cout << "Enter value";
    getline(cin, y);
    array<char, strlen(y)>state;

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(y); ++i)
        cout << state[i] << ' ';

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tip of the day: your `y` is only a char

Comment: Please post the errors too. It not only helps people trying to help  (who can figure out even without it) you but is also good for reference.

Comment: string y;

my bad,and thanks VusP

wow..it all of a sudden wants to work now, well the thing to learn is that char can't hold all that data, i guess :/

thank you

Comment: What is the *point* of the `state` variable? Can't you just use `y`?

Comment: x variable is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` needs a compile-time size, so cannot be instantiated with `strlen`. Furthermore, `strlen` does not work with `std::string`, it expects a pointer to `char`, pointing to the beginning of  null terminated string.

You could use an `std::vector<char>` instead:

```
std::string y;
std::cout << "Enter value";
std::getline(std::cin, y);

std::vector<char> state(y.begin(), y.end());

for(int i = 0; i < state.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << state[i] << ' ';
```

On the other hand, why not just use the `string` `y` directly? Do you really need the "array"?

```
for(int i = 0; i < y.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << y[i] << ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope it will work..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
int x = 4000;

  string y;

  cout << "Enter value";

  getline(cin, y );
  char *b = new char[y.length()];
  int j=y.length();


//array< char, strlen(y)>state;

for( int i = 0; i<j; ++ i )
{//whatever uu want
}
  //cout << state[i] << ' ' ;


system( "PAUSE" );
 return 0;
   }
```

Comment: The question is about C++, not C#.

Answer (score 0):

std::array is a wrapper template class around a C static array. This means that it's dimensions must be known at build time (not runtime).

Here's a short version of a working code that's also a little faster since string::length() is called once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string y;

    cout << "Enter value";
    getline(cin, y );

    for( size_t i = 0, yLen = y.length(); i < yLen; ++i )
        cout << y[i] << ' ';

    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}
```

If you like pointer tricks and take advantage that string's buffer is contiguous in memory (by the C++ standard) your code can look like:

```
int main()
{
    string y;

    cout << "Enter value";
    getline(cin, y );

    for( const char* p = &y[0]; *p; ++p )
        cout << *p << ' ';

    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for the condition *p, how does that work? Shouldn't it be the last element in the loop, not the first? Like...I get the starting point, but the endpoint doesn't make sense to me. 

-Thanks

Comment: sorry forgot to address:

@egur

btw how does the loop do a bounds check, like why doesn't that result in an infinite loop, because *p could go on forever, technically?

Comment: @Shinji-san: `*p` is either zero (end of string - false) else true. Every string end with zero. This will work when you are sure that this is a legal string. I'm sure it's legal since I'm accessing y's internal buffer and std::string store a standard NULL terminated C string.